# Linear regression of boxplot in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, boxplot

I have this data, of a time series:

```
my_data=list()
my_data[["t1"]]=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,2,1,1,1,2)
my_data[["t2"]]=c(2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,1,4,4,2,1,3,2,2,3)
my_data[["t3"]]=c(3,4,5,2,3,4,5,4,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,5,2)
my_data[["t4"]]=c(4,5,3,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,2,7,8,5)
my_data[["t5"]]=c(6,7,5,6,5,6,7,6,7,6,5,6,7,6,7,7,8,8)
boxplot(my_data)
```

I would like to do a linear regression among the boxplots, and plot the trend line on it, possibily with the R coefficient, as in this example:

[image]

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean.  Do you want the regression line through the means of the boxes?  The jagged line that  connects the means?  Also, did you really mean to go from 0 to 2 and then increase by 1 for the variable names?

Comment: I'd say on the median rather than the means...
Sorry I just skipped the t1, I renamed the data from t1 to t5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the regression using `lm` and plot it with `abline`

```
boxplot(my_data)
Meds = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = sapply(my_data, median))
abline(lm(y ~ x, data=Meds))
```

[image: Boxplot with regresion line]

Comment: perfect! it's what I wanted! many thanks !